# Satellite 6 Job Invocation search query : using facts (faster)

Tags: redhat, satellite

I'm using Satellite 6 to manage EL 5, 6 and 7x hosts.
I've been trying to perform a Job Invocation (via Monitor-> Jobs -> Run Jobs) on a host of servers, based on a custom fact that I wrote (the fact is called ad_domain and basically tells you whether its active directory joined or not).

However I can't figure out how to do this....is this even possible?
I'm a Satellite newbie...I don't even even know what parameters I can use in the Search Query to do this. Can anyone help enlighten? Is it possible to specify a factor/facter value(s) in the Search Query so that it will resolve only to hosts that match that value(s)?

Appreciate your help in advance,
Sue

Answer (score 0):

You can try

facts.ad_domain = value